# Mysql column type for text with ascii icons

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, ascii

i have a textarea witch user can insert ascii characters(icon mostly) in it, when i try to insert it into my table :

with `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8_unicode_ci` every thing after the first ascii icon is removed and i am left with whatever text that was before the icon

with `utf8mb4_general_ci` and`utf8mb4_unicode_ci` all the ascii icons are converted to ?

so whats the best column type to save text with ascii icons in it ? do i need to escape them before inserting ? how ?

here is a sample of the text:

```
   
☎️ 041 3381 33 63
☎️ 041 3443 73 57
```

Comment: did u check UTF-8 and HTML doctype???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found the answer my self, i had to set the connections character sets to `utf8mb4` too, with the `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` column.

```
'db'            => [
    'driver'         => 'Pdo_Mysql',
    'database'       => 'telegram',
    'hostname'       => 'localhost',
    'driver_options' => [
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'utf8mb4\'',
    ],
    'username'       => 'root',
    'password'       => '',
],
```

And of course the client and server too

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

source : https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4